# Connect-VIServer failed

Tags: powershell, vmware, rundeck, powercli

Trying to automate the connection to VCenter with a rundeck Job. The powershell script works within powershell when I use it; however, It fails to run properly when used with rundeck.
The script is:

```
if(-not (Get-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -ListAvailable)){
    Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -AllowClobber -Force -Confirm:$false
}
Connect-VIServer -Server $ipaddr -User $usrnme -Password $pswd
Get-VM $vm | Select-Object @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[0])}}
```

The error I see in rundeck is a simple
`Connect-ViServer` The ssl connection could not be established, see inner exception

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adding the parameter `-Force`

To the end of the line containing:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server $ipaddr -User $usrnme -Password $pswd   
Get-VM $vm | Select-Object @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[0])}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This resolved the error `Connect-VIServer The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception` running PowerCLI 12.4 and Powershell 7.2.1.

```
Connect-VIServer -Server $ipaddr -User $usrnme -Password $pswd
```

Adding -Force to the end

```
Connect-VIServer -Server $ipaddr -User $usrnme -Password $pswd -Force
```

Comment: This reiterates the guidance given in [@MarkD’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66339944/3025856) from nearly a year ago. Please be sure to review existing answers before contributing a new one. Once you have more reputation, you’ll be able to upvote previous answers as a way of validating their guidance.